# DropDownListFor valores selecionados não persistem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, bootstrap, razor

Estou utilizando Asp.net C# com mvc 4 e na minha View tenho um DropDownListFor, com uma classe que usei do bootstrap-multiselect, como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o código na view:

```c#
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Estagios, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Estagios, new { @class = "multiselect form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

Quando faço a busca, faço um Post em um método no Controller e dentro desse método (tanto get, como post) alimento a ViewModel e o SelectList:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, ele está pegando os valores que postei, que são 1, 3 e 5. Eu dou um Return View passando a ViewModel. Quando ele posta e a pagina recarrega, ele assume o valor na querystring certinho e faz todo o tratamento da busca certinho conforme programei, porém ele não assume os valores selecionador no DropDownList, trazendo somente o primeiro da lista:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo algo errado?

O plugin utilizado do css/javascript é esse: 
davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se esse teu jeito funciona com o MultiSelect.

Faz assim, teu HTML vai ser um ListBox e não um DropDownListFot

```
 @Html.ListBox("Estagios", null, new { @class = "multiselect-group-clickable" })
```

Seu Script vai ser

```
   <script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Estagios').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        maxHeight: 200
    });

});
</script>
```

E teu controller não vai chamar um SelectList e sim um MultiSelect

```
ViewBag.Estagios = new MultiSelectList(_estagioService.ListarEstagios(), "EstagioId", "Nome", estagios);
```

Verifica os nomes das variáveis pra testar..

Comment: Consegui fazer mas efetuei algumas mudanças do que você me passou.

No controller eu mantive:
ViewModel.Estagios = new SelectList(_estagioService.ListarEstagios(), "EstagioId", "Nome", estagios);

Na View:
@Html.ListBox("Estagios", Model.Estagios, new { @class = "multiselect-group-clickable" })

Coloquei a função Jquery que você passou e funcionou corretamente.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Se achar que ajudou, pode aceitar como resposta, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Você deve usar um MultiSelectList:
    ViewBag.itens = MultiSelectList(itens, "id", "Nome", itensSelected);


//E no html:
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Estagios, (SelectList)ViewBag.itens, "Selecione")
```

Comment: Sua resposta não é clara o suficiente. Elabore uma resposta com contexto, explique o que está errado e pontue os itens alterados. Seja claro e responda sempre com o máximo de detalhes possível.